# Communication between iOS Application and .NET Application?

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 applications, one is iOS app and one is .NET app. I want my iOS app send an message (call a method of .NET app, send some string to .NET app to save to database). So, how can my iOS app can communicate with .NET app?

Comment: When you say .NET "app", does that mean that it's an application external to the IPhone (say, hosted on a website somewhere), a windows application, or a .NET class library that you want to use within your IPhone app?

Comment: Whats you level of knowledge on either .net and iphone dev?

Comment: @Ryan Brunner: Yes, i mean a windows application run on PC:)

Comment: @leduchy, generally speaking, an iphone application and a windows application running on a client machine will not be able to communicate with each other. It's possible, but judging from what you're describing it doesn't sound like the right approach. You will most likely need to add a server side component that communicates (via webservices or some other method) with both clients.

Comment: I have an button in iOS app and when i press this button i want iOS app call a method of .NET app to do something (show an alert and save something to DB). Should i use webservices to do? I really don't known about webservices.

Comment: Sorry, i'm student. Exactly, i will study about webservices next semester. So, i don't known about it now but i can learn if it's nessesary :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to communicate with a desktop application on a local network, Bonjour discovery (also called ZeroConf) may be the way to go.  Apple makes the Bonjour SDK for Windows [freely available](https://developer.apple.com/opensource/index.html), so it appears to be reasonably easy to integrate with your desktop .NET application.  Bonjour is already present as part of the networking services in the iPhone SDK.

Using Bonjour, you can transparently detect the presence of an iPhone running your application on the local network from your desktop client (and vice versa), making the process of connecting the two trivial.  Once networked, you can send whatever data you want between the two.  I show an example of this in action in the video for the networking portion of my [advanced iPhone development course on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).

Comment: Thanks Brad Larson. This info is very usefull for my course project.

Comment: Looks like a comprehensive video, a tad long perhaps (2.5 hours!) but worth watching

Answer (score 1):

Create web services for whatever messages you need sent to your .net app. Then look at `NSURLConnection` to figure out how you can make those 2 communicate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with domino (and I voted his response as an answer).  .NET web services would be the way to make this work.  Web Services were created with the intent of allowing applications on different architecture and technology to communicate together.  If you are looking to build an iPhone app that reports usage or saves user data "in the cloud", you would need to have the iPhone app call a .NET web service.

Comment: I also need my iPhone app tell .Net app show an alert, can i do it with webservices. Sory about this question because i don't known about webservices. :D