# How can I make an iPhone look like a specific Bluetooth device to Windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, winapi, bluetooth

I want to use an iPhone to emulate a Windows Bluetooth device and use this device to control my Win32 application.  For example, I'd like to receive and process (in my Win32 application) messages sent from this device as I would for a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard.

However, I am new to iPhone development and Windows device emulation.  Where should I start to do this job?  Are there any references or code examples I should look at?

Comment: The iPhones bluetooth interface isn't public and you won't be able to activate a certain bluetooth profile on it. If you don't care about the App Store, please don't mind this comment, otherwise: Start filing bug reports about this, maybe they will change it.

Answer (score 3):

On a non-jailbroken iPhone you don't have access to the low-level interfaces for the Bluetooth hardware, so you can't do this.  If you're in the Made for iPod program, you can design Bluetooth accessories that can communicate with an iPhone, but even then you can't make an iPhone look like another Bluetooth device to your Windows system.

I'd recommend instead looking at using WiFi networking and Bonjour discovery to allow communication between your iPhone and your Windows application.  Several applications do this to allow for data to be transferred between Windows and iOS devices.  I provide a few more details about this approach in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458438/comunication-between-ios-application-and-net-application/3459375#3459375).

Answer (score 0):

You should start by studying the Bluetoot protocol specs from bluetooth.org, I don't think that what you are intending to do can be called Windows device emulation. For me is sounds more like a client/server application over Bluetooth, where the iPhone is the client and Windows machine is the server.

For Win32 API I would point this tutorial: [Winsock2 Bluetooth](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4j.html) if you plan to develop in C/C++. Another good option for you would be 32feet.net library.